# How to disable cts:highlight in search:search API?

Tags: marklogic

My search query is taking long time.
When I see the results in `profiler` in `qconsole` I am seeing `cts:highlight` is taking the max time.

Even in search options I have not defined any `search:highlight` option?

I have two questions on this.

1. How to stop search:search API to highlight the term?
2. Even if there is no option of `search:highlight` why `cts:highlight` is getting used?

Answer (score 2):

Search snippets are on by default with search:search.  In other words, the default for options is equivalent to:

```
<transform-results apply="snippet"/>
```

To turn them off completely, add this to your search options:

```
<transform-results apply="empty-snippet" />
```

I'm not sure how long a "long time" is for you.  But when I ran into the problem in the past, I found it was because I was matching some very long documents.  I was matching government bills which have a lot of text in them.  What I did was write a custom snippeting function which checked how many characters are in each document.  If there were more than 100K characters (I don't remember for sure if that was the length--do some testing to find the right length), I would truncate the text before I sent it to cts:highlight.  That allowed me to have snippets on all documents without things slowing down on the very long documents.